# Iterator interface SCJP

Tags: java, scjp

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class TryMe {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List list = new LinkedList<String>();

        list.add("one");
        list.add("two");
        list.add("three");

        Collections.reverse(list);

        Iterator iter = list.iterator();

        for (Object o : iter) {
            System.out.print(o + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

This question is from SCJP , i have problem in understanding iterator and iterable.

I know iterator is an interface with iterator method. Why we cant use for each loop in case of iterator? Compiler says: can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.iterable. what is this? i tried alot to search but didnt get answer

Please Reply

Comment: Because an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) **is not** an [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). Those are two different interfaces.

Comment: you iterate on iterable not on iterator

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863182/what-is-the-difference-between-iterator-and-iterable-and-how-to-use-them

Comment: @RC. it's not related, it's a possible dup

Comment: By the way, the compiler is pretty clear about your problem: *can only iterate over an **array** or **an instance of `java.lang.Iterable`***, so you can't iterate over an `Iterator`

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between `Iterable` and `Iterator`.  An [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is an object that iterates over elements of *another* object, the `Iterable`.  An [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) is what contains the elements and supplies the `Iterator` object (with the `iterator()` method) that iterates over the `Iterable`'s elements.

The enhanced `for` loop must take an `Iterable`, so that it can call `iterator()` to get a guaranteed new `Iterator` to iterate over the elements implicitly.

This is enforced by the [JLS, Section 14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2):

> The enhanced for statement has the form:
>
> ```
> EnhancedForStatement:
>     for ( FormalParameter : Expression ) Statement
> ```

and

> **The type of the *Expression* must be `Iterable` or an array type (§10.1), or a compile-time error occurs.**

Answer (score 0):

The `List` is `Iterable`, the `Iterator` is not.

This will work:

```
    for (Object o : list) {
```