# Difference between Iterator and Iterable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the difference between Iterator and Iterable? Is one sub-type of the other or not? What are the actual differences in some real applications?

I am trying to read some tutorials and specifications, but they are all very complicated.

(I am using ES6 and Babel, if that helps.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863182/what-is-the-difference-between-iterator-and-iterable-and-how-to-use-them

Comment: To those voting for closing: How is this too broad? I am asking for two related, concrete concepts in a specific language. (I am not complaining, just asking for more info.)

Comment: @Lashane that question is about Java, I am using ES6, that's a different language

Comment: the proposed duplicate is about another similar language, where the concept is identical (possibly replicated from).

Comment: From a language-independent standpoint: an iterator is an object you can use to iterate over the contents of a container, and an iterable is an object that can provide an iterator for its contents. Unsure if that will help, but perhaps it will?

Comment: @Claies OK, that is a real answer I was looking for. That it's the same in ES6 as in Java :) Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Exploring ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_iteration.html) by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer:

> An iterable is a data structure that wants to make its elements accessible to the public. It does so by implementing a method whose key is Symbol.iterator. That method is a factory for iterators.
>
> An iterator is a pointer for traversing the elements of a data structure (think cursors in databases).

Comment: Both this answer and the proposed duplicate helped me, so I marked this question as answering and the proposed duplicate as duplicate