# what's the point of having both Iterator.forEachRemaining() and Iterable.forEach()?

Tags: java, foreach, iterator, iterable

and both of them get a Consumer as parameter. so if Java 8, is meant to avoid confusions, like it has done in Time API, why has it added a new confusion? or am I missing some point?

Comment: are you trying to compare `Iterator` and `Iterable`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863182/what-is-the-difference-between-iterator-and-iterable-and-how-to-use-them

Comment: @JBNizet all right guys, don't throw tomatoes on me! I got it :D

Answer (score 107, accepted):

To understand why the two methods both exist, you need to first understand what are `Iterator` and `Iterable`.

An `Iterator` basically is something that has a "next element" and usually, an end.

An `Iterable` is something that contains elements in a finite or infinite sequence and hence, can be *iterated* over by keep getting the next element. In other words, `Iterable`s can be iterated over by `Iterator`s.

Now that you understand this, I can talk about what's the difference between the two methods in question.

Let's use an array list as an example. This is what is inside the array list:

```
[1, 3, 6, 8, 0]
```

Now if I call `Iterable.forEach()` and pass in `System.out::print()`, `13680` will be printed. This is because `Iterable.forEach` iterates through the whole sequence of elements.

On the other hand, if I get the `Iterator` of the array list and called `next` twice, before calling `forEachRemaining` with `System.out::print()`, `680` will be printed. The `Iterator` has already iterated through the first two elements, so the "remaining" ones are 6, 8 and 0.

Comment: all right. thanks for your clear and complete answer.

Comment: Ok, but where is the difference between forEach() and forEachRemaining() ? https://pl.kotl.in/ehW6pBa5t

Comment: @Malachiasz What part of my answer did you not understand? `forEach` iterates through the elements of an `Iterable`. `forEachRemaining` iterates through the remaining elements of an `Iterator`.

Comment: In my linked sample forEach iterates also through the remaining elements. Or does forEach() in Kotlin I used is not the same as Iterable.forEach() in Java?

Comment: @Malachiasz Ah... I didn't understand what you meant by the link. Well, this answer is about Java's `Iterable.forEach` vs `Iterator.forEachRemaining`. I am not an expert in Kotlin. It appears that in Kotlin, `Iterator` also has a `forEach` method that works exactly like `forEachRemaining`. I suggest you ask a new question if you want more accurate info on that.

Answer (score 3):

In Simple word, forEachRemaining() is an improved version of Iterator, where before JDK8 we were uses hasNext(), next() to traverse the any collection(ArrayList, HastSet etc).

```
List<String> fruits= new ArrayList<>();
fruits.add("Apple");
fruits.add("Banana");
fruits.add("Grapes");
fruits.add("Orange");
Iterator<String> iterator = fruits.iterator();
```

**Before JDK8**

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Now In JDK8 if we want to we want to traverse any collection we can do like this:

**After JDK8**

```
iterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

> Now, JDK8 forEach() is improved version JDK7 with lamda expression.

Answer (score 0):

Just summarizing for Scala and Kotlin users: in Java, `Iterator`'s `forEach` is called `forEachRemaining` (while `Iterable` has a `forEach` method).

Answer (score 0):

Additional comment to @Sweeper's answer:

`forEach` is for `Iterable`, which corresponds to a "collection", thus "for each" is "for each element of the collection".

`forEachRemaing` is for `Iterator`, which corresponds to a pointer. There may or may not be a "collection" behind the pointer; "for each element of a pointer" is not valid statement.